# Undefined index: ratings_score .../wp-postratings.php on line 994

Tags: plugins, errors, plugin-wp-postratings

Recently i activated debug mode on my wordpress blog and the following error occurred .

```
 Notice: Undefined index: ratings_users in C:\wamp\...\wp-postratings.php on line 994
```

The code is :

```
if(is_null($post_ratings_data)) {
    $post_ratings_data = get_post_custom($post_id);
    **$post_ratings_users = intval($post_ratings_data['ratings_users'][0]);**
    $post_ratings_score = intval($post_ratings_data['ratings_score'][0]);
    $post_ratings_average = floatval($post_ratings_data['ratings_average'][0]);
}
```

Any Solution ?

Answer (score 1):

when ever you expect something to be an array, it's good practice to check to see if it is first before proceeding. so the new code might read like this:

```
if(is_null($post_ratings_data)) {
    $post_ratings_data = get_post_custom($post_id);
    if ( is_array( $post_ratings_data['ratings_users'] ) ) {
        $post_ratings_users = intval($post_ratings_data['ratings_users'][0]);
        $post_ratings_score = intval($post_ratings_data['ratings_score'][0]);
        $post_ratings_average = floatval($post_ratings_data['ratings_average'][0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: its still giving the same error, any other suggestion ?

Comment: notices are not really a problem, you should probably look for fatal errors, sometimes they are hidden in the output due to css issues. Other than that, there are too many variables to help you with.

Comment: its works fine ... all i wanted is to make it clear, without notices

Comment: edited, as always I should have read the error message more slowly. :) the system is expecting $post_ratings_data['ratings_users'] to be an array, but for whatever reason it's not.